# azure bicep function app with event grid trigger from storage account - how to create a function resource for event grid subscription?

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-bicep, azure-eventgrid

I am trying to deploy FunctionApp with an Event Grid Trigger, upon a blob creation within Storage Account. I can succesfully create FunctionApp, Storage Account, as well as Event Grid Topic, however I am struggling with creation of a Function resource (I need that for the Event Grid Subscription). What could be wrong in the template below?

`modules/FunctionApp/Function.bicep`:

```c
@allowed([
  'http'
  'eventgrid'
])
param triggerType string = 'http'

param functionAppName string


resource functionApp 'Microsoft.Web/sites@2022-09-01' existing = {
  name: functionAppName
}

// var functionApphref = 'https://${toLower(functionAppName)}.azurewebsites.net'

var functionName = (triggerType == 'eventgrid') ? 'EventGridTrigger' 
: 'HttpTrigger'


resource function2inModule 'Microsoft.Web/sites/functions@2022-09-01' = if(triggerType == 'eventgrid') {
  parent: functionApp
  name: functionName
  // location: location
  properties: {
    // script_href: '${functionApphref}/admin/vfs/home/site/wwwroot/function_app.py'
    // test_data_href: '${functionApphref}/admin/vfs/tmp/FunctionsData/${functionName}.dat'
    // href: '${functionApphref}/admin/functions/${functionName}'
    // config: {}
    language: 'python'
    isDisabled: false
  }
}
```

In the above template you can see some lines commented out - my intention (for now) is to skip them and just create a "placeholder function" under Function App for the Event Grid Subscription. (I hope that's possible?). For now, I am planning to deploy application code later with "Deploy to Function App..." in VSCode.

This is the `main.bicep` (relevant bits):

```c
// storage account for data
module storageAccount4data 'modules/Storage/StorageAccount.bicep' = {
  name: storageAccount4dataName
  params: {
    location: location
    storageAccountName: storageAccount4dataName
  }
}

// blob service
module blobServices 'modules/Storage/BlobService.bicep' = {
  name: 'default'
  params: {
    blobServiceName: 'default'
    storageAccountName: storageAccount4data.outputs.dtls.name
  }
}

// container
module container 'modules/Storage/Container.bicep' = {
  name: containerName
  params: {
    storageAccountName: storageAccount4data.outputs.dtls.name
    blobServiceName: blobServices.outputs.name
    containerName: containerName
  }
}


var functionApp2Name = '${funcAppNamePrefix}-2-preProcAndWriteToDB'

module functionApp2 'modules/FunctionApp/FunctionApp.bicep' = {
  name: functionApp2Name
  params: {
    location: location
    functionAppName: functionApp2Name
    functionStorageAccountName: storageAccounts4func[1].outputs.dtls.name
    // triggerType: 'eventgrid'
  }
}


// event grid resources
resource systemtopic 'Microsoft.EventGrid/systemTopics@2023-06-01-preview' = {
  name: eventGridTopicName
  location: location
  identity: {
    type: 'SystemAssigned'
  }
  properties: {
    source: storageAccount4data.outputs.dtls.id
    topicType: 'Microsoft.Storage.StorageAccounts'
  }
}
// the above deploys without any problems


// This is the problematic part:
module function2 'modules/FunctionApp/Function.bicep' = {
  name: 'function2Name'
  params: {
    functionAppName: functionApp2.outputs.functionAppName
    triggerType: 'eventgrid'
  }
}

// Later aim to create the following resource:
// resource eventsubscription 'Microsoft.EventGrid/systemTopics/eventSubscriptions@2023-06-01-preview' = {
//   parent: systemtopic
//   name: functionApp2.name
//   properties: {
//     destination: {
//       properties: {
//         resourceId: '${functionApp2.outputs.functionAppId}/functions/EventGridTrigger'
//         maxEventsPerBatch: 1
//         preferredBatchSizeInKilobytes: 64
//       }
//       endpointType: 'AzureFunction'
//     }
//     filter: {
//       subjectBeginsWith: '/blobServices/default/containers/${containerName}/blobs/'
//       subjectEndsWith: '.json'
//       includedEventTypes: [
//         'Microsoft.Storage.BlobCreated'
//       ]
//       enableAdvancedFilteringOnArrays: true
//     }
//     labels: []
//     eventDeliverySchema: 'EventGridSchema'
//     retryPolicy: {
//       maxDeliveryAttempts: 30
//       eventTimeToLiveInMinutes: 1440
//     }
//   }
// }
```

The error I get is:

```bash
Encountered an error (ServiceUnavailable) from host runtime.
(Target: /subscriptions/{}/resourceGroups/{}/providers/Microsoft.Resources/deployments/function2Name)
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: so azure function v4 / python3+ ? are you using the out of the box eventgrid trigger ?

Comment: @Thomas yes v4/python3+ BUT this question is purely about bicep/ifra, i am not deploying the logic to the function yet. I am trying to establish if I can have a placeholder function so that I can create an event grid subscription resource

Comment: yeah but it sometimes behave differently based on language / function runtime. GA is often different for python / dotnet / java etc ....

Comment: anyway thanks, i will give it try

Comment: After my workaround, it seems like there is an issue with the `triggerType: 'eventgrid'` while passing to the functions. This one only throws host run time error. @average.everyman

Comment: @Jahnavi could you please elaborate? what is your workaround?

Comment: After I tried so many attempts in my environment, I was able to deploy it successfully as [shown](https://i.imgur.com/jKqzQzA.png). And host runtime is a very transient error which disappears automatically after 3-4 deployments. Make sure that you are using latest API versions of the resource providers. @average.everyman

Comment: @Jahnavi sounds promising. could you please share the code that resulted in succesfull deployment?

Comment: Do you want me to share the complete code or only the event subscription creation or function code. @average.everyman

Comment: Creating event grid trigger function via portal and then deploying event subscription code via bicep will works for you? @average.everyman

Comment: @Jahnavi not really... the whole point for me was to deploy everything in one go using `azd up`, so I don't want to fiddle in the portal

Comment: @Jahnavi could you please share the code for function placeholder creation? Currently I'm also working on implementation, that would allow me to deploy functions just by `azd up`, but for some reason it just doesn't work at all and I do not understand why

Comment: Can you raise a new question mentioning your requirement to resolve it! @SergeyKrutilin